# can't change name to uploaded file using multer

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

I am trying to change the name of the image im uploading to the server using `multer` which gives the file a random name.
I user `multer.diskStorage` method to do so as described in the documentation but it keeps saving the file with random names

CODE:

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null,'./uploads/')
    },
    fileName: (req,file,cb) => {
        cb(null, file.originalname)
    }
})
const upload = multer({storage: storage})


router.post('/', upload.single('carImage') ,(req, res) => {

    res.send(req.file);
}
```

RESPONSE :

```
{ 
  fieldname: 'carImage',
  originalname: 'testOCR8.jpg',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
  destination: './uploads/',
  filename: '229f70c20e5550dbe638db49791ef17d',
  path: 'uploads/229f70c20e5550dbe638db49791ef17d',
  size: 1712380 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> im uploading to the server using multer which gives the file a random name

You made a typo. It is `filename` not `fileName`. This is the standard behavior as per [the docs](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#diskstorage).

> `filename` is used to determine what the file should be named inside the folder. If no `filename` is given, each file will be given a random name that doesn't include any file extension.

So, your code should be

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null,'./uploads/')
    },
    filename: (req,file,cb) => { // notice the change 'filename'
        cb(null, file.originalname)
    }
});
const upload = multer({storage: storage});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a different approach for using StorageMulter. Try the following -

```
var StorageMulter = multer.diskStorage({
   destination: function(req, file, callback) {
      callback(null, "./temp");
   },
   filename: function(req, file, callback) {
      var uploadFileName = "x.jpg"; //Manipulate this variable accordingly
      callback(null, uploadFileName);
   }
});

var upload = multer({
   storage: StorageMulter
});

app.post("/api/uploaddocument", function(req, res) {
   upload(req, res, function(err) {
      if (err) {
         return res.end("Something went wrong!"+ err);
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: where is the fieldname going? like here `upload.single('carImage') ` the 'carImage'

Comment: Check out the line saying - "var uploadFileName = "x.jpg". You change x.jpg to anything you want the file to be named.

Comment: no i got it but `multer` need the `fieldname` as well